# ASPX page when rendered displays Source on IE8 Browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

HI,
I have a pagge which containf largde amount of data in Dropdown and after the page is rendered to client Side.
It shows the Source of the page.

This happens to few pages and in **IE8 Browser.**

What may be the problem ?

Comment: Please provide us with some code. It's impossible to help you with just your explanation.

Comment: When we right click the page and click on View Source, in Similar way, the page is rendered.

Comment: I really don't understand the problem anymore. Isn't that the way it is supposed to be when you choose "view source" from your browser?

Comment: I think he means that the browser displays the source of the page, rather than the rendered content of the page upon loading.

Comment: @Jason Berken - you are right.

Comment: A large amount of data in a Dropdown doesn't sound like a good UI decision. As Joop said, it would be easier if you could provide some code. Are you sure that this is the dropdown control's fault? Or have you HTML Encoded your text, which is then being displayed as strings instead of being rendered as controls?

Comment: I agree with TenaciousImpy, a drop down with a large number of values isn't a good UI choice.

But, to prove whether or not it is the cause of the problem, I would suggest cutting the contents of that drop down to just a few values. Then if you still get the problem, it's not the drop down's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Did you somehow set the MIME type incorrectly? Perhaps it is set to text/plain rather than text/html? Or is it possible that your web server is not set properly to handle your file extension?